# Best practices for resizing images on actionscript 3 (flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image

i want to make a site similar to http://svenprim.com/ but when i resize image on AS3 using simple MyObject.width=AnyValue the image always gets pixalated, even is the proportions WxH are correct. In the site i gave you, as you can see the images always get resized in a beatifull way without any distortion (not so munch) when you resize the browser.

So, How can i resize by code images loaded into my flash applications without loosing a lot of quality?.  THANKS!

Comment: Are you kidding? The page you linked to doesn't use Flash at all...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're loading them with Loader, on the complete handler try this:

```
Bitmap(loader.content).smoothing = true;
```